# Passing a certain number of rows into a function in R

Tags: r

I would like to pass 1500 rows into a function until reaches the end of the dataset. Currently I hard coded the number of rows
My code

```
AA1 = AA[1:1500,]
AA2 = AA[1501:3000,]
AA3 = AA[3001:4500,]
AA4 = AA[4501:6000,]
AA5 = AA[6001:6573,]
#passing into the function generate_pa
AAdone1 = generate_pa(AA1)
AAdone2 = generate_pa(AA2)
AAdone3 = generate_pa(AA3)
AAdone4 = generate_pa(AA4)
AAdone5 = generate_pa(AA5)
```

Is there anyway I can do this efficiently? Should I create a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can also use `by` which does the `split-apply-combine` step together. Since you already have two methods to split the data every `n` rows, I'll show another way using `gl`.

```
n <- 1500
by(AA, gl(ceiling(nrow(AA)/n), n)[1:nrow(AA)], generate_pa)
```

This splits the data every 1500 rows and applies `generate_pa` function to each chunk.

Comment: is there anyway I can then combine all the generated data into a dataframe?

Comment: @Hal yes, did you try the answer ? What did it return ?

Comment: Yes I did. It outputs all the data on the console. I tried doing 'save=by(AA, gl(ceiling(nrow(AA)/n), n)[1:nrow(AA)], generate_pa)' but it didn't work.

Comment: do `output <- by(AA, gl(ceiling(nrow(AA)/n), n)[1:nrow(AA)], generate_pa)` and check `output` now.

Answer (score 1):

you can split a data.table into chunks of size `chuncksize` using `data.table::split`

You can then feed the resulting list `l` to any function using `lapply( l, ...)`

what it actually does:
`setDT(AA)` converts AA to a data.table
`[, rowID := (.I-1) %/% chunksize]` create a new column, based on rownumber integer division, `.I` is used, becasue `data.table` does not have rownames.
The result is then split by the newly created `rowID`-column.

```
#sample data
set.seed(123)
AA <- data.frame( data = rnorm(10))

#     data
# 1  -0.56047565
# 2  -0.23017749
# 3   1.55870831
# 4   0.07050839
# 5   0.12928774
# 6   1.71506499
# 7   0.46091621
# 8  -1.26506123
# 9  -0.68685285
# 10 -0.44566197

chunksize = 3
l <- split( setDT(AA)[, rowID := (.I-1) %/% chunksize][], by = "rowID")

# $`0`
#          data rowID
# 1: -0.5604756     0
# 2: -0.2301775     0
# 3:  1.5587083     0
# 
# $`1`
#          data rowID
# 1: 0.07050839     1
# 2: 0.12928774     1
# 3: 1.71506499     1
# 
# $`2`
#          data rowID
# 1:  0.4609162     2
# 2: -1.2650612     2
# 3: -0.6868529     2
# 
# $`3`
#         data rowID
# 1: -0.445662     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nearly similar approach to the on of Wimpel:

```
sequence <- 1:6573

lists <- split(sequence, ceiling(seq_along(sequence)/1500))

lapply(lists, generate_pa)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `nr` is the number of rows in the input data frame and `k` is the number of rows in each chunk then using the builtin `anscombe` data.frame for reproducibility then either of these `split` lines will create a list of chunks.  You can `lapply` your function to that. No packages are used.

```
nr <- nrow(anscombe)
k <- 3 # 1500 in your case

split(anscombe, rep(1:nr, each = k, length = nr))

# or
split(anscombe, droplevels(gl(nr, k, nr)))
```